# PHP form validation using substr

Tags: php, validation, substr

I'm trying to make a program that accepts string even if it is misspelled as long as the first 2 letters is correct. Earlier when i run my program it works fine but when i put this

```
if(substr($player1, 0, 2) === "rock" || substr($player2, 0, 2) === "rock")
```

then click submit it will not print anymore. What did i do wrong with my code?  or what function is supposed to be use?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</h1>
<?php


print ('<form action="" method="post">');
print ('<p>Player 1: <input type="text" name="p1" /></p>');
print ('<p>Player 2: <input type="text" name="p2" /></p>');
print ('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="PLAY" />');
print ('</form>');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $player1score = 0;
    $player2score = 0;
    $draw = 0;
    $player1 = strtolower($_POST['p1']);
    $player2 = strtolower($_POST['p2']);

    if(substr($player1, 0, 2) === "rock" || substr($player2, 0, 2) === "rock"){

            if ($player1 == 'scissors' && $player2 == 'scissors') {
            $draw++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
    }

            else if ($player1 == 'rock' && $player2 == 'rock') {
            $draw++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
    }

            else if ($player1 == 'paper' && $player2 == 'paper') {
            $draw++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
    }

            else if ($player1 =='rock' && $player2 =='scissors') {
            $player1score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
    }

            else if ($player1 == 'rock' && $player2 =='paper') {
            $player2score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";

    }

        else if($player1 == 'scissors' && $player2 == 'rock') {
            $player2score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";

    }

        else if ($player1 =='scissors' && $player2 =='paper') {
            $player1score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";

    }
        else if ($player1 =='paper' && $player2 =='rock') {
             $player1score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";

    }

        else if ($player1 =='paper' && $player2 == 'scissors') {
            $player2score++;
            print "Player 1: $player1score<br>";
            print "Player 2: $player2score<br>";
            print "DRAW: $draw";
    }
}
}
?>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Because your condition isn't correct.. And if the condition isn't correct it will return false and won't enter the if..

Comment: `substr($var, 0, 2)` will never return with more than 2 characters,  so it will never be identical to a string with 4 characters (rock)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the string `'rock'`, because the `substr` will only return 2 characters, not 4.

Here is what you should do:

```
// Checking for "rock", but only care about the beginning of "ro" ck
if(substr($player1, 0, 2) === "ro" || substr($player2, 0, 2) === "ro")
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Tried this when i saw  @HPierce comment but still it won't print. when I input player1 = roks player2 = rocks.

Comment: I agree this is an answer 2 his question, but please let some people think for themselves istead of just feeding them without letting them think first..

Comment: @kingleonidas2 It will still not work because you are not being consistent.
If you only use the `substr` in the first `if` it will only work in that if, but it will fail on the rest of `if` statements.
You need to use the same way in all the ifs.